# Action sheet is not getting dismissed on clicking outside the popup

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiactionsheet, uitapgesturerecognizer

In ios  7.0 I just want to close that action sheet whenever the user presses outside of that popover.I am showing that action sheet on button click and using this code trying to get some tap gesture on actionsheet.window

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"button clicked");
    NSLog(@"action sheet ");
    actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil                                                         delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Rename",@"Delete",@"Cancel" ,nil];


    for (UIView *subview in actionSheet.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)subview;
            [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [button setTitleColor:[UIColor orangeColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

            [button setTitleColor:[UIColor orangeColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button setTitleColor:[UIColor orangeColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        }
    }
    //  [actionSheet setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];


    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapOut:)];
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [actionSheet.window addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    [actionSheet.window addGestureRecognizer:tap];

}

-(void)tapOut:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"in tap out");
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:actionSheet];
    if (p.y < 0) {
        NSLog(@" p.y < 0 ");
    }
}
```

But am not getting this tap gesture.Please help me in solving this.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is my solution to dismiss the actionsheet when you tap outside

First create  one view to handle the tap gesture and the action sheet

```
@implementation MyClass
{
    UIActionSheet *_myActionSheet;
    UIView *_myTapView;
}
```

on the actionsheet delegate method

```
- (void)didPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
{
    [_myTapView removeFromSuperview];
    _myTapView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:actionSheet.superview.bounds];
    _myTapView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapOut:)];
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [_myTapView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    [actionSheet.superview insertSubview:_myTapView belowSubview:actionSheet];
}
```

and handle the tap gesture

```
- (void)tapOut:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
//dismiss the action sheet here
    [_myActionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:<index> animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add a tapgesture on different then `actionSheet.window`.

Please try to add tapgesture on `self.superView`

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapOut:)];
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; 
[self.superview addGestureRecognizer:tap];
//OR
[actionSheet.superview addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Like this, you can try different thing based on view hierarch.

**Update 1**

Try to subclass the Actionsheet and define tapgesture in class it self like.

```
-(void)tapOut:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self];
    if (p.y < 0) { // They tapped outside
        [self dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    }
}

-(void) showInView:(UITabBar *)view {
    [super showFromTabBar:view];

    // Capture taps outside the bounds of this alert view
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapOut:)];
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; // So that legit taps on the table bubble up to the tableview
    [self.superview addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
```

Enjoy Coding!!

Comment: Yes I tried even that..   UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapOut:)];
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    actionSheet.superview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
   [actionSheet.superview addGestureRecognizer:tap]; but not getting into that method

Answer (score 0):

The following applies to a subclass of a UIActionSheet

```
 actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil                                                         delegate:self
                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                            destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                 otherButtonTitles:@"Rename",@"Delete" ,nil];


for (UIView *subview in actionSheet.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)subview;
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor orangeColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor orangeColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor orangeColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }
}
//  [actionSheet setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

Comment: But am not showing actionsheet from tab bar am using showInView I tried adding [actionSheet.superView addGestureRecognizer:tap]

Comment: i think problem is that the action sheet overlap your whole view with transparent view that why you not get the tap gesture.

Comment: Yes then how can we close that when user taps outside of the actionsheet

Comment: Could you help me in solving this?

Comment: i try but didnot find any solution for your issue

Comment: I tried adding a subview to action sheet and adding tap gesture for that view but in vian..that subview is not getting added to actionsheet   UIView *background = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    background.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
     [actionSheet addSubview:background];

Comment: hi @Snigdha comment your actionsheet code and put my edited code might it help you.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot by using cancelButtonTitle we can do that. It's amazing.Thankyou so much

Answer (score -1):

This code helps you to dismiss the action sheet

```
[self dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Button Index '0' is cancel button's button index.

Comment: I want to close the sheet when user touches anywhere outside the actionsheet not on button click

Comment: Yes , this will do the trick use this code inside your tapout function .

Comment: When I tap on the screen that tapout function is not getting called.That is the exact problem

Comment: Could you please help me in solving this?